# date difference in months in javascript

Tags: javascript

Need date Difference in terms of months.

If I give the FromDate as 1st Feb,2011 and ToDate as 2nd April 2011 then Its should give result as 2.2.

That means It should calculate the months first then the number of days in the decimal value.

See if date difference is 3 months and 22 days then It should give the difference as 3.22

Is it possible through the Javascript.

Comment: there are so many related question to your question already been asked on SO. See related section.

Comment: Shouldn't 1st Feb 2011 to 2nd April 2011 be 2.1 months?

Comment: go here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp and do the math

Comment: see [dateJS](http://www.datejs.com/)

Comment: @Ates Goral of course stackoverflow :D

Comment: Also, what happens when you compare 15 Jan to 10 March? 3? 2.xx?

Comment: Then how can you see the difference between 2 months and 3 days (2.3) and 2 months and 30 days (2.30) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var date1 = new Date(2011, 1, 1);
var date2 = new Date(2011, 3, 2);
var diffYears = date2.getFullYear() - date1.getFullYear();
var diffMonths = date2.getMonth() - date1.getMonth();
var diffDays = date2.getDate() - date1.getDate();

var months = (diffYears * 12 + diffMonths);
if (diffDays > 0) {
  months += '.' + diffDays;
} else if (diffDays < 0) {
  months--;
  months += '.' + (new Date(date2.getFullYear(), date2.getMonth(), 0).getDate() + diffDays);
}
console.log(months)
```

Comment: I know this is a VERY old answer, but for the record, it's wrong. It doesn't cater for date1's month being greater. but year being smaller than date2's.

Comment: It is indeed a very old answer. But I couldn't reproduce the issue you mention. If date1's month is greater than date2's, diffMonths will be negative and the maths will still be good. Am I missing something?

Comment: LOL, no you're not missing something, looks like I missed it. Thanks for replying.

Comment: 1) Explain what your code does and how it answers the question and 2) Use code snippets

Answer (score 1):

See http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/caja/demos/calendar/time-cajita.js# for an RFC 2445 date/time library.

`time.durationBetween` returns a duration value that is the difference between two dates.

You can see usage examples in the [unittests](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/tests/com/google/caja/demos/calendar/time_test.js)

Answer (score 1):

not exact but you can get a rough estimate with this:

```
var d=new Date(2010,00,01); //start date
var dd=new Date(2010,11,31); //end date
var dif=dd-d //get difference in milliseconds
var m=dif/(86400000*30); //1000*60*60*24=>86400000 gives one day
```

It gives 12.133~ for above dates.

Answer (score 0):

the example below gives result 2.2 for your dates

```
var d1 = new Date(2011, 1, 1);
var d2 = new Date(2011, 3, 2);

var ydiff = d2.getYear() - d1.getYear();
var mdiff = d2.getMonth() - d1.getMonth();
var ddiff = 1 + d2.getDate() - d1.getDate();

var diff = (ydiff*12 + mdiff + ".") + ddiff;
alert(diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that it helps. 100% works.

```
    var startDate = '13.06.2013'; // for example (i got it from input)
    var endDate = '12.02.2016'; // for example
    var temp_sd = explode('.', startDate);
    var temp_ed = explode('.', endDate);
    var row_id = $(this).attr('row_id');

    var m_arr = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]; // 365 days in year
    var m_arr_vis = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]; // 366 days
    var temp_year = parseInt(temp_sd[2]);
    var temp_month = parseInt(temp_sd[1]);
    var daysInM, temp_s, temp_e, m_diff = 0;
    while(true) {
        if(temp_month === parseInt(temp_sd[1])) {
            temp_s = parseInt(temp_sd[0]);
        } else {
            temp_s = 1;
        }
        if((temp_year%4) === 0) {
            daysInM = m_arr_vis[temp_month-1];
        } else {
            daysInM = m_arr[temp_month-1];
        }
        if(temp_month === parseInt(temp_ed[1])) {
            temp_e = parseInt(temp_ed[0]);
        } else {
            temp_e = daysInM;
        }

        m_diff += (temp_e-temp_s+1)/daysInM;

        //alert(temp_s+' -> '+temp_e+' . '+temp_month+' . '+temp_year);
        //alert(temp_e-temp_s+1);
        //alert(daysInM);
        if((temp_year === parseInt(temp_ed[2]))&&(temp_month === parseInt(temp_ed[1]))) break;
        // inc temp_month
        if(temp_month<12) {
            temp_month++;
        } else {
            temp_month = 1;
            // inc temp_years
            temp_year++;
        }
    }

    var months = Number(m_diff).toFixed(7);
```

...

```
    function explode( delimiter, string ) { // Split a string by string
    // 
    // +   original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   improved by: kenneth
    // +   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)

    var emptyArray = { 0: '' };

    if ( arguments.length != 2
            || typeof arguments[0] == 'undefined'
            || typeof arguments[1] == 'undefined' )
    {
            return null;
    }

    if ( delimiter === ''
            || delimiter === false
            || delimiter === null )
    {
            return false;
    }

    if ( typeof delimiter == 'function'
            || typeof delimiter == 'object'
            || typeof string == 'function'
            || typeof string == 'object' )
    {
            return emptyArray;
    }

    if ( delimiter === true ) {
            delimiter = '1';
    }

    return string.toString().split ( delimiter.toString() );
}
```